# is there an iTunes javascript api

Tags: javascript, itunes, itunes-sdk

is there any javascript API to access iTunes ?

for example, I want to retrieve the list of my iTunes albums in a web page using javascript. 
i read something about a COM interface, but this should work in non-Windows environments too.

Comment: @Tulon Please stop making minor, pointless changes to every post you encounter! Your minor edits adds nothing but clutter to the post, so I'll rollback them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is now, but this will likely change in 10.10 as they seem to be introducing JS for Automation at that point:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/index.html

I would expect that whatever you can do via Applescript will then be something that can be accomplished by JS too.